# 360 degree equirectangular projection of all naked eye stars with precessional motion for simulating

Tags: star, coordinate, constellations, ecliptic, sky-survey

For many years now I've been using Voyager sky simulator by Carinasoft. The projection selections are great, but Equirectangular doesn't seem to one one of them. Is there a program out there that does this? I cooked up an Excel sheet to do the coordinate conversions, and I can import these into Autocad if I have to, but it seems like there should be an off-the-shelf package to do this.

For my current project I need to be able to show a 360 degree overview of changes due to precession from 3000-2000-1000 BC at a glance.  It may be my familiarity with the typical simple projection published for surveyors in a standard Ephemeris before the internet and GPS all but eliminated the demand for such publications.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but for equirectangular just map RA = x and dec = y

Answer (score 2):

The "cylinder" projection of Stellarium does this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it.  I see the date you used is today's. Have you experimented with a few thousand years BCE?

Comment: I haven't, but Stellarium does handle precession and nutation, so it should work properly for dates in the distant past/future